# How to get a boolean 2D array according to vector index condition, with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, vector, boolean, conditional-statements

According to a vector and a fixed size:

```
vector = np.array([2, 5, 0])
fixedsize = 5
```

I want to create a boolean 2D matrix with shape (len(vector), fixedsize) with True values until the jth index represented in the vector, False elsewhere:

```
boolmatrix = np.array([[True, True, False, False, False], # True until the 2nd element
                       [True, True, True, True, True], # True until the 5th element
                       [False, False, False, False, False] # True until the "0th" element
                      ])
```

I'm looking around `np.where` but I don't find good answers to my problem.
What is the best *pythonic* way of doing this? *Preferentially by taking advantage of broadcasting and vectorized operations in numpy*, if possible.

Thanks in advance for your answers,

Mathieu

Answer (score 1):

A *pythonic* way of doing what you're looking for would be list comprehensions:

`boolmatrix = [[x<val for x in range(fixedsize)] for val in vector]`

If you want to work with numpy arrays, you can convert the result with `np.array(boolmatrix)`.

### Edit for performance

If you're looking for performance, I can suggest a cython version - which is anything but pythonic, but gets the job done performance-wise and makes the most of the embarrassingly parallel nature of the problem using openmp.

```py
# cell magic for jupyter notebook testing:
# %%cython --compile-args=-fopenmp --link-args=-fopenmp
import cython
from cython.parallel import prange

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def make_boolmatrix(long[:] vector, int fixedsize):
    """
    vector should be np.int64
    """
    boolmatrix = np.zeros((vector.shape[0], fixedsize), dtype=bool)
    cdef np.uint8_t[:, :] boolmatrix_view = boolmatrix
    cdef int i, j
    cdef long val
    
    for i in prange(vector.shape[0], nogil=True):
        val = vector[i]
        for j in range(fixedsize):
            boolmatrix_view[i,j] = (j<val)
    return boolmatrix
```

Comment: Thanks @seon for your answer, that's effectively a good way to start and I've implemented it this way in the first place. However, by *pythonic*, I meant the fastest and scalable possible (I have millions elements in my vector) and I wish to find a solution avoiding for loops -> taking advantage of broadcasting and vectorized operation  in numpy *if possible*)

Comment: I haven't got a clue how to translate the code to vectorized numpy - I did however edit my original answer to include a cython version, which may be anything but _pythonic_ but gets the job done performance-wise.

Answer (score 0):

```
olmatrix = np.empty(len(vector), dtype=list)
for row, j in enumerate(vector):
    trues = np.repeat(True, j)
    olmatrix[row] = np.append(trues, np.repeat(False, fixedsize - j))
```